# Is a Preorder with a Direction Necessarily a Poset?

Tags: order-theory

In *A Comprehensive Course in Analsysis* by Barry Simon (p. 96) [(Available in Google Books here.)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Real_Analysis/7brzrQEACAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1), Simon defines a *directed set* as a **partially ordered** set $Z$ with the property that for all $\alpha, \beta \in Z$, there exists $\gamma$ with $\gamma > \alpha, \gamma > \beta$.

The Wikipedia article on *directed set* [(link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) defines defines a *directed set* as a **preordered** set $Z$ with the property that for all $\alpha, \beta \in Z$, there exists $\gamma$ with $\gamma \geq \alpha, \gamma \geq \beta$.

In trying to reconcile the two definitions I am wondering:  *Is it the case that any **preordered** set with a **direction** (i.e. the property that for all $\alpha, \beta \in Z$, there exists $\gamma$ with $\gamma \geq \alpha, \gamma \geq \beta$) must be **antisymmetric** and as such automatically a [partially ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Partial_order_relation) set?*

Answer (score 1):

No.

Example 1:  The words in a dictionary ordered alphabetically but only by *first* letter is a [preordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) set (reflexive and transitive) with a direction (since for any two words in the dictionary they will both be $\leq$ "zero").  However, this set is not a [partially ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Non-strict_partial_order) set since it is not antisymmetric (e.g. "parallel" $\leq$ "poset" and "poset $\leq$ "parallel" despite the fact that "parallel" $\neq$ "poset").

Example 2:  The [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) article on Wikipedia gives another example or a preordered set with a direction that is not a partially ordered set.  The example given in the diagram that appears [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) is the natural numbers but ordered by the integer part of $x/4$.  That is, $x \leq y$ provided $\left \lfloor{x/4}\right \rfloor  \leq \left \lfloor{y/4}\right \rfloor$ (in the article they write this as $x//4 \leq y//4$).  Again, this is a preordered set with a direction, however it is not a partially ordered set due to the fact that it fails to be antisymetric (e.g. "5" $\leq$ "6" and "6" $\leq$ "5" despite the fact that "5" $\neq$ "6").

Comment: Or, for a trivial way of getting as many counterexamples as you wish, pick some directed set $D$ and, for some $d\in D$, replace it with $d_1,d_2$, with $d_1\leq d_2\leq d_1$ and for all $x,y\in D$ such that $x\leq d \leq y$, make $x\leq d_i\leq y$. This is the opposite of making a poset out of a pre-ordered set, by taking the quotient by $\sim$, where ${\sim} = {\leq}\cap{\geq}$. See [Preorders and partial orders on partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder#Preorders_and_partial_orders_on_partitions).